# How is CSS getting loaded/applied to a Component even though I am not passing it as props?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am following an online tutorial which has an `index.css` file which is imported in the `index.js` file as: `import './index.css';`

After that the App component is is rendered in `index.js` like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Now I what I am having difficulty understanding is that how is the CSS being applied to the App component even though I am not passing it as a prop.

How is the App component able to access the CSS even without props ?

Comment: This looks like a CRA generated application -- when the application is deployed (or run in dev mode), Webpack sees the CSS import and appends it to the DOM as a traditional `<style>` tag that defines certain classes; the DOM is then able to use those classes as any other webpage would.

Comment: By default, JavaScript `import` can only handle other JS modules `export`ed from other JavaScript files. But Webpack (and other bundlers) makes it possible to `import` other non-JS assets into JavaScript files—e.g. SVG, CSS, JPG, etc. As @lux noted, `import`ed CSS via Webpack will then loaded to `head` area and be accessible to all things in the DOM.